# Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout

Tags: spark-streaming

I am learning something about spark streaming and I have got a program which is designed to find the top 5 words.

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds

object Top5{
   def main(args:Array[String]){
  val conf=new SparkConf()
  conf.setAppName("AppName")
  conf.setMaster("spark://SparkMaster:7077")
  val ssc=new StreamingContext(conf,Seconds(10))
  val hottestStream=ssc.socketTextStream("SparkMaster：7077", 9999)
  val searchPair=hottestStream.map(_.split("")(1)).map(item=>(item,1))
  val hottestDStream=searchPair.reduceByKeyAndWindow((v1:Int,v2:Int)=>v1+v2,Seconds(60),Seconds(20))
  hottestDStream.transform(hottestItemRDD=>{
    val top5=hottestItemRDD.map(pair=>(pair._2,pair._1)).sortByKey(false)
                 .map(pair=>(pair._2,pair._1)).take(3) 
     for(item<-top5){
       println(item)
     }
    hottestItemRDD}
  ).print()
  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
}}
```

As I am performing it in the spark cluster environment, the error says

```
Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
```

I have searched my question in stackoverflow. And there is a similar question [org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.lookupTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346855/org-apache-spark-rpc-rpctimeoutexception-futures-timed-out-after-120-seconds) The answer tells me  to increase `spark.timeout.network`, is that right? Besides, where can I find `spark.timeout.network`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For heavy workloads it is recommended to increase `spark.network.timeout` to 800 seconds:

```
--conf spark.network.timeout=800
```

This is described in the [IBM documentation](https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2016/07/18/troubleshooting-and-tuning-spark-for-heavy-workloads/) about troubleshooting and tuning Spark for heavy workloads.

Comment: If my Spark Streaming application's driver isn't responding within 120 seconds (the default) then I'd be trying to find out why, not raising the timeout until the problem goes away. An answer to a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43384061/60585 - really explains what to look at - are the executors or the driver under memory pressure?

Comment: This one is purely a Workaround and never a final solution. We need to work on the delay caused.