# Spark 2.4.0 Master going down

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

We are running Spark 2.4.0 / Scala 2.11 and we run few Spark streaming applications listening on Kafka topics.

It is Spark Kafka Direct streaming API, we are running 4 Spark streaming applications listening to 4 different topics.

We receive an average of 10-20 msgs per second. The Spark master is going down after 1-2 hours of it running. Exception is given below. Along with that spark executors also get killed.

This was not happening with Spark 2.1.1 it started happening with Spark 2.4.0 any help/suggestion is appreciated.

The exception that we see is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1713)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply from 192.168.43.167:40007 in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:216)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:216)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:326)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:326)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:293)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:136)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:157)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:78)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:54)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:106)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.tryFailure(Promise.scala:112)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryFailure(Promise.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$NettyRpcEnv$$onFailure$1(NettyRpcEnv.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anon$1.run(NettyRpcEnv.scala:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply from 192.168.43.167:40007 in 120 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you *could* keep increasing the timeout until the problem "goes away", that's really only dealing with the symptom. In a Spark streaming app you probably never want to be waiting 120 seconds to find out that something has failed. Certainly in ours, with a batch time of 10 seconds, we'd rather find out much sooner.

I think this similar question/answer ([org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.lookupTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346855/org-apache-spark-rpc-rpctimeoutexception-futures-timed-out-after-120-seconds/43384061#43384061)) goes on to add useful tips when dealing with this situation - investigate whether the Executor or Driver are under memory pressure: 1-2 hours after start seems a likely amount of time for that to start showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the spark.rpc.askTimeout value to a value greater than default.